# PostgreSQL - How to yield a FK in JSON?

Tags: json, postgresql

I made a procedure in which I am looking to insert a sale order, which has n sale details. The problem is that I want to make the sale order yield its ID to the sale details in the "saleOrderId" of the second insert. How could I do it?

Another question, what is the alternative to the "json_array_elements" for a single element?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE prc_create_sale_order("saleOrder" JSON, "saleDetail" JSON)

LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' 
AS 
$$
BEGIN

-- DECLARE "orderId" INT;

INSERT INTO tbl_production_sale_orders(id, "customerId", "sellerId", "creationDate", "estimatedDeliveryDate", "deliveryDate", subtotal, vat, total, "createdBy")
-- El operador ->> devuelve el campo del objeto JSON como texto y no como JSON (usando ->).
SELECT  (o->>'id')::INT,
        (o->>'customerId')::INT, 
        (o->>'sellerId')::INT, 
        (o->>'creationDate')::TIMESTAMP, 
        (o->>'estimatedDeliveryDate')::TIMESTAMP, 
        (o->>'deliveryDate')::TIMESTAMP,
        (o->>'subtotal')::INT,
        (o->>'vat')::INT,
        (o->>'total')::INT,
        (o->>'createdBy')::INT
FROM json_array_elements("saleOrder") AS o;

INSERT INTO tbl_production_sale_details("saleOrderId", "productId", "boxesNumber", "piecesNumber", status, "createdBy", "createdAt", "updatedBy", "updatedAt")
SELECT  (d->>'saleOrderId')::INT, 
        (d->>'productId')::INT, 
        (d->>'boxesNumber')::INT, 
        (d->>'piecesNumber')::INT, 
        (d->>'status')::INT, 
        (d->>'createdBy')::INT, 
        (d->>'createdAt')::TIMESTAMPTZ, 
        (d->>'updatedBy')::INT, 
        (d->>'updatedAt')::TIMESTAMPTZ
FROM json_array_elements("saleDetail") AS d;

COMMIT;
END;
$$;

CALL prc_create_sale_order(
                            '[
                                {"id": 95, "customerId": 1, "sellerId": 1, "creationDate": "2022/06/16 17:50:30", "estimatedDeliveryDate": "2022/06/16 17:50:30", "deliveryDate": "2022/06/16 17:50:30", "subtotal": 800, "vat": 70, "total": 870, "createdBy": 5}
                            ]',
                            '[
                                {"saleOrderId": 7, "productId": 1, "boxesNumber": 10, "piecesNumber": 100, "status": 1, "createdBy": 5, "createdAt": "2022/06/16 17:50:30-05", "updatedBy": 5, "updatedAt": "2022/06/16 17:50:30-05"},
                                {"saleOrderId": 7, "productId": 1, "boxesNumber": 70, "piecesNumber": 700, "status": 0, "createdBy": 5, "createdAt": "2022/06/16 17:50:30-05", "updatedBy": 5, "updatedAt": "2022/06/16 17:50:30-05"}
                            ]');
```

Comment: Which `"saleOrderDetail"` are you talking about?

Comment: "*what is the alternative to the "json_array_elements" for a single element?*" - you could use `saleDetail[0]` or `saleDetail->0` - but really, just don't pass an array?

Comment: You might want to have a look at `json_populate_recordset` btw, it seem more appropriate for your use case

Comment: My bad. I meant "saleOrderId".